# Code first table name error when many to many table insert

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, insert, many-to-many

Yesterday I asked a question and later I say solved the problem. But today the same error occurred again.

I have three tables `dbo.Food`, `dbo.Menu` and `dbo.FoodMenu` which is the many-to-many link table - like this:

- dbo.Food { ID, FoodName }
- dbo.Menu { ID, MenuName }
- dbo.FoodMenu  { FoodID, MenuID }

I want to insert Food id and Menu id into FoodMenu table. My context is ok, my mapping is ok, codes and `Exception` below. Please help.

```
public JsonResult FoodMenu(FoodMenuViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ManyDbContext ctx = new ManyDbContext();

        foreach (var item in vm.MenuIds)
        {
            ctx.FoodMenus.Add(new FoodMenu { FoodID = vm.FoodId, MenuID = item });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new { Result = true, Mesaj = "" });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { Result = false, Mesaj = "" });
    }
}
```

Exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>   SqlException: Invalid object name '**dbo.FoodMenus**'.

Context:

```
        public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FoodMenu> FoodMenus { get; set; }
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Food>()
            .HasMany<Menu>(s => s.menus)
            .WithMany(c => c.foods)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("FoodID");
                cs.MapRightKey("MenuID");
                cs.ToTable("FoodMenu");
            });
```

What I understand from this error is: my table's name is `dbo.FoodMenu` but exception says: it must be `dbo.FoodMenus`. Yet I don't know why.

Here is my FoodMenu `class` ;

```
public class FoodMenu
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int FoodID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int MenuID { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: You may try this option:
`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}`

Comment: I tried this but when the project startup an error occured:               FoodMenu1: Name: The EntitySet 'FoodMenu1' with schema 'dbo' and table 'FoodMenu' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.
'

Comment: Am seeing this question again and will now want to ask as I asked before, how were the db models generated?, The exception says you don't have a table FoodMenus. I would also expect you to get that exception when trying to insert food because the context says Foods

Comment: i dont get exception to insert Food table because Foods is a variable, not a class name. db models generating is not problem except FoodMenu table. i want to give new info: when i was get this exception i tried to cahange the table name of FoodMenu from database. new table name was FoodMenus which the exception's want and click continue button. when i run same process again ,  insert process successful. so i think solved the problem but when i was restart, another exception occured naturally.

Comment: @ibrahimgenc can you post FoodMenu class to question

Comment: FoodMenu class added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this problem. So I created two one to many mapping to insert into the FoodMenu table. one for Food and one for Menu. solved my problem, I can insert now. I do not have any problems in the get process too.

My FoodMenu `class`;

```
public class FoodMenu: AuditableEntity, IBaseDomain

    {
        public int FoodID { get; set; }

        public int MenuID { get; set; }

        //------------------------------------------------

        public Food food { get; set; }

        public Menu menu { get; set; }
    }
```

and mapping below;

```
public FoodMenuMap()
        {
            ToTable("FoodMenu");

            Property(x => x.FoodID)
                .HasColumnName("FoodID")
                ;

            Property(x => x.MenuID)
                .HasColumnName("MenuID")
                ;

            //One to Many FluentApi

            HasRequired<Food>(s => s.food)
            .WithMany(g => g.foodFoodMenus)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.FoodID);

            HasRequired<Menu>(s => s.menu)
            .WithMany(g => g.menuFoodMenus)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.MenuID);

        }
```

navigation properties of Food and Menu classes;

Food:
`public List<FoodMenu> foodFoodMenus { get; set; }`

Menu:
`public List<FoodMenu> menuFoodMenus { get; set; }`